# Cannot resolve symbol 'INTERNET'

Tags: android-studio, android-permissions

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET }, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

I get the error in above code:
Cannot resolve symbol 'INTERNET'
in android studio project.

I also add code in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I have very lack of knowledge as I just start learning few days ago.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring internet permission in the manifest, like you did, is sufficient.
There is no need to request it at runtime with ActivityCompat.requestPermissions.

Also check that you import the correct library:
import android.Manifest